# Ссылка на временный объект в параметрах по умолчанию

Tags: c++, ссылки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, Почему здесь не образовывается висячей ссылки?
Если я что-то то вывожу в деструкторе, то она печатается после выхода из функции.

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
 Wrapper() :w() {}
 operator T&() const {return const_cast<T&>(w) ;}

private: 
  T m;
};

struct A
{
A() :p(new int(1)) {}
int* p;
}

void foo(A& a= Wrapper<A>()){...}
```

Comment: Деструктор созданного временного объекта будет вызван после возврата функции, все верно. Другое дело, что странно присваивать lvalue ссылке ссылку на временный объект.

Comment: Так в этом и суть ссылка не продлевает жизнь временного объекта, например, void foo(A& a = A()) запрещено, а тут используется какой-то хак и я хочу понять на чем он основан

Comment: `A& a = A()` запрещено потому что временный объект нельзя биндить к lvalue ссылке. Никакого продления не происходит в любом случае.

Comment: А здесь разве не будет Wrapper временным объектом? Лучше же не возвращать ссылки на внутреннее состояние рвалью объекта, чтобы такого не происходило даже добавили реф аннотации методов.

Comment: Будет. Но он не биндится к lvalue ссылке, к ней биндится возвращаемое значение оператора.

Comment: Что-то я совсем запутался, почему тогда деструктор враппера вызывается после выхода из функции. Прикладываю для удобства ссылку на годболт https://godbolt.org/z/EE8Pq1Kz4

Comment: В общем, посмотрел в сгенерированный ассемблером код, выходит, что вызов этих параметров по умолчанию происходит на стороне вызывающей функции, поэтому они и будут жить до конца функции foo.

Comment: Все правильно, временный объект создается, функция вызывается и возвращается, выражение, где он был создан заканчивается, он разрушается.